# Can't cut titles that are too long

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of javascript that should check the length of all the titles on my website and cut them if they are too short, however this doesn't happen. Why?

```
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("newsTitle");
for (i=0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    if (titles[i].length > 14) {
        var oldTitle = titles[i].value;
        var newTitle = oldTitle.substring(0,10) + "...";
        titles[i].innerHTML = newTitle;
    }
}
```

Everything in body

```
<div id="header">
    <h1 id="headerTitle">WIP</h1>
    <ul id="headerList">
        <li class="headerListButton"><a href="http://mastermeredith.com" class="headerListText">Home</a></li>
        <li class="headerListButton"><a href="about.html" class="headerListText">About</a></li>
        <li class="headerListButton"><a href="archives.html" class="headerListText">Archives</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="newsHolder">
    <!--News pieces go here-->
    <?php
        $newsPieces = scandir("posts", 1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($newsPieces) and $i < 12; $i++) {
            if ($newsPieces[$i] != "." and $newsPieces[$i] != "..") {
                $titlefile = fopen("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/title.txt", "r");
                $textfile = fopen("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/text.txt", "r")
                $fullElement = "<div class='newsPiece'><div class='newsImageHolder'><img class='newsImage' src='posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/image.jpg'></div><div class='newsContent'><h1 class='newsTitle'>" . fread($titlefile, filesize("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/title.txt")) . "</h1><p class='newsText'>" . fread($textfile, filesize("posts/" . $newsPieces[$i] . "/text.txt")) . "</p><a class='newsLink' href='post?post=" . urlencode($newsPieces[$i]) . "'>Continue Reading</a></div></div>";
                echo $fullElement;
                fclose($titlefile);
                fclose($textfile);
            }
        }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("newsTitle");
        for (i=0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            if (titles[i].length > 14) {
                var oldTitle = titles[i].value;
                var newTitle = oldTitle.substring(0,10) + "...";
                titles[i].innerHTML = newTitle;
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you reading from `.value` and assigning to `.innerHTML`? Have you tried debug-printing your modified strings?

Comment: What is the browser + version you are experiencing the issues with? Have you tried debugging your JS with Chrome or console.log?

Comment: I've tried assigning to innerHTML and value, both don't work.

Comment: I'm using chrome, console log shows nothing.

Comment: Also, *why must this be client-side Javascript?* Has anyone heard of delivering complete finalized pages from the server anymore?  It is absurd the amount of crap like this that simply does not need to exist on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `.innerHTML` instead of `titles[i].value`;,

```
var oldTitle = titles[i].innerHTML;
```

because as I understood `titles` are not inputs, also you need check title length

```js
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("newsTitle"),
    title;

for (var i = 0, len = titles.length; i < len; i++) {
    title = titles[i].innerHTML;
    
    if (title.length > 14) {
        titles[i].innerHTML = title.substring(0,10) + "...";
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="newsTitle">Test title</h1>
<h1 class="newsTitle">Test title Test title Test title</h1>
<h1 class="newsTitle">Test title Test title Test title</h1>
<h1 class="newsTitle">Test title Test title Test title Test title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the length of `titles[i].innerHTML`

```
if (titles[i].innerHTML.length > 14) {
    var oldTitle = titles[i].innerHTML;
    var newTitle = oldTitle.substring(0, 10) + "...";
    titles[i].innerHTML = newTitle;
}
```